# Make Lotus Notes mail sent by .NET program save sent mail to a different folder

Tags: windows, windows-xp, .net-framework, lotus-notes

I have a .NET program that runs on my PC (Windows XP Pro) that periodically sends automated email messages through my Lotus Notes client.

Is there a way in my .NET code that I can tell it to save the sent mail to a different Lotus Notes folder and not in my normal Sent mail folder? I want my Sent mail folder to only contain emails I send myself, and not have my program's sent mail mixed in.

Comment: Sounds like it would be easier to setup Lotus Notes to move these emails after the email is sent.

Comment: If you are the programmer of the .NET application, you should be asking this question on StackOverflow instead of on SuperUser.  (Check out the FAQ.  SuperUser is not intended for programming questions.)  If you are not the programmer, then you should ask the programmer to give you that feature.  It is certainly possible to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies for posting this here. It really should have been posted to StackExchange, but I do thank you Torsten Link for your comment. It got me halfway there. And in case I've piqued anyone's interest, I'll go ahead and post my solution.

The first thing I had to realize is that Folders and Views are two different things.

- A view will list documents based on a pre-defined search criteria.
- A folder contains documents that have been marked as being in that
  folder.

So while I could use `NotesDocument.PutInFolder(FolderName)` to get a copy of the note into the specified folder, it didn't "remove" it from the sent view.

To remove it from the Sent view, I had to cause it to fail the Sent view's search criteria. In this case here is the code for the sent view.

`SELECT DeliveredDate = "" & PostedDate != "" & !(@IsMember("S"; ExcludeFromView))`

This means the following.

`Show the document in the view if the field "DeliveredDate" is blank and PostedDate is not blank, and the field ExcludeFromView does not contain an "S".`

So, to keep the item from showing up in the Sent mail view, I had to add an "S" to the existing value in the ExcludeFromView field.

```
NotesDocument.AppendItem("ExcludeFromView", "S")
NotesDocument.Send(False)
NotesDocument.PutInFolder("Automated Sent")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that this is the wrong place and belongs to Stackoverflow... But the answer is to use the PutInFolder Method of the NotesDocument Class: `NotesDocument.PutInFolder(FolderName)`

Comment: Thank you! I think this is exactly what I was looking for.